# How do I curl to Docker within Airflow?

Tags: docker, airflow

I have airflow with `DockerOperator` working using [this](https://github.com/benjcabalona1029/DockerOperator-Airflow-Container).
Hello world works OK.

Now my Docker image when run as a container outside of Airflow exposes an API which I can access like:

```
curl --request POST --url http://0.0.0.0:8080/somepath
```

but if I change my dag:

```
curl = "curl --request POST   --url http://0.0.0.0:8080/somepath"

dop = DockerOperator(
    api_version="1.37",
    docker_url="TCP://docker-socket-proxy:2375",
    command=curl,
```

I get:

`Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8080 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server`

so what should the `command` be? TIA!

Comment: `0.0.0.0` means (sort of) localhost. If you `curl http://0.0.0.0`, you're trying to access a web server running in the same machine where the `curl` command is run. When you create a `DockerOperator` (any docker container, for that matter, and this is not related to Airflow but to Docker) you get sort of a **different** virtual machine. Which is proOOoobably not running any web server. TL;DR: You're trying to access a local web server in a machine that is not running any server. I imagine that server is running in your computer? BUT that's a different machine than the one spawned by Docker.

Comment: Thanks but my docker container runs a uvicorn webserver.

Comment: I misunderstood... Though... The `curl` that works does it work when run inside the docker container (with `exec`)? AFAIK `uvicorn` tries to pick port `8000`, not `8080`. When running as an isolated container... Is port `8000` in the container mapped to `8080` in the host, by any chance? Also, in your GitHub, where you have the "Hello world" example (in `example.py`), the image for your Docker is a vanilla `ubuntu`. I suppose that image changes when you try to run the `curl` test?

Comment: Hah, good spot, thanks. I changed 8080 to 8000. Same error and yes the image is different.